# Understanding of Weighted Shift Operators, Analytic function Theory by Allen Shields

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

I was given a paper by **Allen Shields on Weighted shift operators and analytic function theory** to study. I have background in functional analysis and complex analysis but I would say, I have spent more time than usual understanding the material. This is because I lack the proper motivation on what brought about the study of weighted shift operators.

Can someone put me through the material, motivations on the concepts in the paper and recommend basic references.

I am asking because the paper, as people say is a famous paper that discusses on the subject. Thank you in advance

Comment: There is some information here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/154511/the-spectra-of-weighted-shifts

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts Thank You very much